# $this->viewPath is not working with CakePHP 3.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.1

I have updated my cakePHP application to 3.1 through composer, and I'm trying to fix all the small or deprecated warnings.

I could easily fix the `$this->layout` stuff but I don't understand how to fix `viewPath` errors.

Looking at the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-1-migration-guide.html) it looks like it should be exactly the same thing:

```
$this->viewPath = 'Element';
```

should become

```
$this->viewBuilder()->viewPath('Element');
```

But this is not working, and the only thing that I get is

```
Error: Call to undefined method Cake\View\ViewBuilder::viewPath() 
File /var/www/myapp/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php 
Line: 375
```

What is the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the very same migration guide, in the View section of it:

> View::$viewPath is deprecated. You should use View::templatePath() instead.

Guess it's now:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->templatePath('Element');
```

Comment: CakePHP 4 and 5: They seem to have finally moved to `setAbc()`/`getAbc()`, so now it's `setTemplatePath();`, not just `templatePath()`